# Is there any way I can show a little menu when I'm hovering over a planet?

Tags: html, css

I would like to show a menu (like in the picture I made on figma).
But when I do the :hover option it doesn't seem to find it, or at least it somehow doesn't work.
I have no idea how I would even start with this, I tried most things, like changing the z-index and stuff, but it doesn't really seem to work.

[image]

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
}
body {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #303a49 0, #151628 100%);
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #2f3234;
    overflow: hidden!important
}
.space .solar-syst {
    position: fixed;
    zoom: 160%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
}

.space .solar-syst div {
    border-radius: 1000px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
}
.space .solar-syst div:not(.sun) {
    border: 1px solid rgba(102, 166, 229, .12)
}
.space .solar-syst div:not(.sun):before {
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute
}
.space .solar-syst div:not(.asteroids-belt):before {
    box-shadow: inset 0 6px 0 -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)
}
.space .sun {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #ffd000 1%, #f9b700 39%, #f9b700 39%, #e06317 100%) -28px -103px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0!important;
    background-size: 175%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(255, 107, 0, .4), 0 0 22px 11px rgba(255, 203, 0, .13)
}

.space .sun:hover{
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.space .mercury {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 7.18673s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 7.18673s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .mercury:before {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    background: #9f5e26;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px
}
.space .venus {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 18.45553s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 18.45553s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .venus:before {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    background: #BEB768;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px
}
.space .earth {
    height: 145px;
    width: 145px;
    margin-top: -72.5px;
    margin-left: -72.5px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 30s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 30s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .earth:before {
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #11abe9;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -3px
}
.space .earth:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 -10px 0 -8px grey;
    -webkit-animation: orb 2.24404s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 2.24404s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .mars {
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
    margin-top: -95px;
    margin-left: -95px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 56.42613s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 56.42613s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .mars:before {
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #cf3921;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -3px
}
.space .jupiter {
    height: 340px;
    width: 340px;
    margin-top: -170px;
    margin-left: -170px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 355.72282s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 355.72282s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .jupiter:before {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    background: #c76e2a;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -9px
}
.space .saturn {
    height: 440px;
    width: 440px;
    margin-top: -220px;
    margin-left: -220px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 882.69525s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 882.69525s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .saturn:before {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background: #e7c194;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px
}
.space .saturn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 2.34%;
    width: 4.676%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-52deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-52deg);
    margin-left: -2.3%;
    margin-top: -1.2%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #987641, 3px 1px 0 #987641, -3px 1px 0 #987641;
    -webkit-animation: orb 882.69525s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 882.69525s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 52% 60%;
    transform-origin: 52% 60%
}
.space .uranus {
    height: 520px;
    width: 520px;
    margin-top: -260px;
    margin-left: -260px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 2512.4002s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 2512.4002s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .uranus:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #b5e3e3;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px
}
.space .neptune {
    height: 630px;
    width: 630px;
    margin-top: -315px;
    margin-left: -315px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 4911.78386s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 4911.78386s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .neptune:before {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #175e9e;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px
}
.space .asteroids-belt {
    opacity: .7;
    border-color: transparent!important;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 179.95583s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 179.95583s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s;
    overflow: hidden
}
.space .asteroids-belt:before {
    top: 50%;
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    margin-left: -105px;
    margin-top: -105px;
    background: 0 0;
    border-radius: 140px!important;
    box-shadow: //this is just so much shadow code//
}
.space .pluto {
    height: 780px;
    width: 780px;
    margin-top: -390px;
    margin-left: -390px;
    -webkit-animation: orb 7439.70741s linear infinite;
    animation: orb 7439.70741s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -90s;
    animation-delay: -90s
}
.space .pluto:before {
    height: 3px;
    width: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -1.5px;
    margin-left: -1.5px
}
@-webkit-keyframes orb {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg)
    }
}
@keyframes orb {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transform: rotate(-360deg)
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="space">
        <div class="stars" id="stars"></div>
        <div class="stars2" id="stars2"></div>
        <div class="stars3" id="stars3"></div>
        <div class="solar-syst" id="solar-syst">
            <div class="sun"></div>
            <div class="mercury"></div>
            <div class="venus"></div>
            <div class="earth"></div>
            <div class="mars"></div>
            <div class="jupiter"></div>
            <div class="saturn"></div>
            <div class="uranus"></div>
            <div class="neptune"></div>
            <div class="pluto"></div>
            <div class="asteroids-belt"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <div class="footer-text">
        Co-Working &copy; - Lukas, Nathan, Matti, Loran - Ghent 2021
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This can help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I figured that already. The problem is that the css file somehow blocks the :hover selector.

Comment: I've tried working this through also. I can't seem to get the `:hover` to work as well on your sun div. I would assume there is some underlying CSS that is affecting the `:hover selector`. I stripped the majority of your CSS and tried to get this behavior to function in a fiddle and I was successful, so I would start there. You may have to restructure some of your `z-index` styles.